# Port Forwarding issue With linux box

Tags: windows

I have a VM box with linux on it. My linux ip is 192.168.234.128 but EE (My ISP) only allows 192.168.1.xxx (This is for port forwarding. Basically EE only allows 192.168.1.xxx ips but my linux box is 192.168.234.128)

I am thinking, should I use NetCat to achieve this? (I am thinking I open a port with netcat and redirect the traffic to my windows computer).

Comment: What's EE? Your question is very vague, I don't understand what your problem is and with what kind of setup you're dealing. Please [edit] it, add more details.

Comment: Edited @gronostaj

Comment: What's your network layout? Which parts of the network can you manage? (configurable routers etc.) What are you trying to achieve? (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029))

Comment: I am trying to port forward 192.168.234.128 but my ISP provider configuration page only allows these kinds of ip's (192.168.1.xxx)

Comment: Please draw your network layout and mark which devices have what IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by myself. There is also an ip which is 192.168.1.73 which is my VM Ware linux system.